# logging into magento 2 customers area using 3rd party API

Tags: magento2, api, authorize

I have a remote API that will validate existing customers' credentials and log them into Magento 2 customers' area.

The target flow is the following:

- Customer visits Magento site
- Fills in username and password
- Submit the form
- Magento will call the API that looks something like this:

  > http://api/login?username=$customer_username&password=$customer_password
- If the credentials are correct, the API will return a json object with user details. Like email, first name, last name...etc
- The customer is logged into Magento.

I figured I need a custom module for this, my confusing is:

- Can I leverage existing Magento login form, or do I need to create my own form + URL + blocks/templates.
- The custom form will have it's Controller that will do all this logic, or is there a way to hook into existing login controller.
- I have to create a user in Magento DB as well.

Thanks in advance.